# issue with writing multipart(embedded image) mimeMessage to .html file

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I need to write email content from hbase to .html file format. I have all data of email in java object. I am using java.email lib for this. However facing issue with writing multipart image MimeMessage to .html file.
I have image embedded in html as follows. I tried different approach without datasource those are the commented lines in below code.

```
        MimeMessage mimeMessage = outlookMsg.toMimeMessage();

        mimeMessage.setFrom("abc@gmail.com");
        mimeMessage.setRecipients(RecipientType.TO, "xyz@gmail.com");
        mimeMessage.setSubject("story completion");

        MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("related");

        // first part (the html)
        MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        String htmlText = "<H1>Hello</H1><img src=\"cid:image\"/>";
        messageBodyPart.setContent(htmlText, "text/html");
        // add it
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        // second part (the image)
        messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        DataSource fds = new FileDataSource(new File("D:\\JAVA\\Practice_Workspace\\pst\\krishna_radha.jpg"));

        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
        //messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID", "<image>");
        messageBodyPart.setContentID("<image>");
        messageBodyPart.setDisposition(MimeBodyPart.INLINE);
        //messageBodyPart.attachFile("D:\\JAVA\\Practice_Workspace\\pst\\krishna_radha.jpg");
        mimeMessage.setContent(multipart);

        File file = new File("D:\\JAVA\\Practice_Workspace\\pst\\htmlemail.html");
        //OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
        mimeMessage.writeTo(os);
        os.flush();
        os.close();
```

I am getting output as below. Image is not getting displayed.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4Sk3.png)

Comment: Does this [JavaMail FAQ entry](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#sendmpr) help?

Comment: Yes. I got it. Thank you.